# in mediapipe face mesh, can i find the angle between landmark connection lines?

Tags: python, math, geometry, mediapipe, face-mesh

Hi I'm a amateur coder(pretty much a beginner) trying to make a project out of computer vision tech.

So far I managed to leave only two connection lines from the original "all-together-showing" code to focus on them.

It would be great if I could calculate the angle of the connection lines and show the angle in arabic numerals. Hoping i could overlap it on the face-mesh.

Would this take too much coding to make the engine heavy?

A rough suggestion of the way to code this function would be of great help please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).